# Create simple WebView with action.VIEW

Tags: android, android-intent, webview, android-manifest, actionview

Hi I've create a simple link browser, but I lost last update to open external URL.

This is the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.browser">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.browser.WebViewActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And this my simple `WebViewActivity.java`

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static Activity controller;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        controller = this;
        mURL = "";
        if (getIntent().getData() != null) {
            setWebViewAndLoadURL(mURL);
        } else {
            this.finishAffinity();
        }
    }
}
```

The method 'setWebViewAndLoadURL' is not important because the action.VIEW not working.

Do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tnx to all.
I found solution.
In XML I must add this to intent-filter:

```
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"/>
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="*"/>
```

And in Activity I must add intent URL:

```
mURL = "";
if (getIntent().getData() != null) {
mURL = getIntent().getData().toString();
    setWebViewAndLoadURL(mURL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the WebView layout in your activity which is more simple.

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />`
```

in your WebViewActivity modify the code with :

```
String url = "https://www.google.com";
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```